# What if I signed a 2 years contract during my probationary period?

Tags: job-offer, resignation, contracts, probation

Okay, so when I was hired, they offered me the job and let me sign 2 years contract. I'm still on my probationary period but I'm starting to realize that I don't like my job. I'm not happy anymore. It makes me depressed. It's a struggle to go to work everyday. Plus, we only have 1 day off and 1 day is not enough to recover from all the stress that I'm getting. What will happen if I don't accept the regularization but I already signed a 2 years contract?

Comment: Read your contract or talk to a legal professional if you don't understand the particulars. This site can't do either of those for you.

Answer (score 3):

The point of a probationary period is so that either party can terminate the contract without the normal repurcussions. Double check your contract to make sure, but it should be fine to leave at any time during your probationary period. Just remember to maintain your professional conduct at all times, and provide any necessary notice as specified in your contract.

Comment: What people often don't quite understand is that a probationary period goes both ways; it's about both you and the employer testing the fit of your relationship, not just the employer verifying how well you fit in the organisation.